# Static members of non static class?

Tags: c#

I have one static member in non static class - if I will initialize this field with some value - does other (new) instances of this class will have the same value in this field?

Comment: Could be a good interview question. I doubt how many people know this. :)

Comment: @HarveySpecter true that :)

Comment: `Static` means independent of instances. Does that answer your question? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah all instances of the same class share the same value of static member.

Comment: I suspect you mean "all instances" - and it's not that each instance has the same value, it's that the variable is associated with the type, not *any* instances.